# Electrical systems with multiple connections to earth - is earth modelled as one region of equal potential here?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, conventions, earth

[image]

In the picture we can see a realization of a TT-System, an electrical system with multiple connections to earth at different localiations. I allready know (from this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75176/does-potential-difference-exist-between-earth-ground-in-geographically-diverse-l?rq=1)) that the coulomb-potential in the earth is not necessarily equal at each point on earth, so it could as well differ between the earthing points shown in the graphic.

However, my question is rather about how the ground and its potential are modelled in circuit theory: In the graphic there are two connections to earth, one from the star point of the system, one from the chassis of the device that is being grounded.

Each of those connections leads through some Resistance (RB and RA) and then to the potential of earth.

Question: Are the two instances of "earth" seen in this graphic supposed to resemble a region of earth that actually has the same potential? In that case the resistances $R_B$ and $R_A$ would be a way to model the fact that at the entrance points, where the electrode is connected to the ground, there may in fact be slightly different electric potentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are exactly right. In circuit diagrams the earth points can typically be imagined as connected together (we just don't draw them to make the circuit simpler). In most low-voltage applications that is even really the case, as all ground points use the same connector on the plug.

In your case, differing potential at different grounding locations seems to be important, which is why the resistors are introduced to model that.